# Make SQL query faster

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can anyone tell me how to make this query faster?

```
$session_id = '000000000015';
$start = 0;
$finish = 30;

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT TOPUSERS.ID, TOPUSERS.USERNAME, TOPUSERS.NAME, TOPUSERS.NAME2, TOPUSERS.PHOTO, TOPUSERS.FB_USERID, TOPUSERS.IMAGE_TYPE, TOPUSERS.TW_USERID, TOPUSERS.TW_PHOTO,

    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(USERS_BUCKETS.ID) FROM USERS_BUCKETS WHERE USERS_BUCKETS.USERID=TOPUSERS.ID),0) AS NUM_ALL,
    COALESCE((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN USERS_BUCKETS.STATUS='Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM USERS_BUCKETS WHERE USERS_BUCKETS.USERID=TOPUSERS.ID),0) AS NUM_DONE,
    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(USERS_LIKES.ID) FROM USERS_LIKES WHERE USERS_LIKES.USERID=TOPUSERS.ID),0) AS NUM_LIKES,

    (SELECT USERS_BUCKETS.BUCKETID FROM USERS_BUCKETS WHERE USERS_BUCKETS.USERID=TOPUSERS.ID ORDER BY USERS_BUCKETS.DATE_MODIFIED DESC LIMIT 1) AS RECENT_BUCKET,
    (SELECT BUCKETS_NEW.BUCKET_NAME FROM BUCKETS_NEW WHERE BUCKETS_NEW.ID=RECENT_BUCKET) AS REC,

    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW.USER_ID=TOPUSERS.ID),0) AS FOLLOWING,
    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID=TOPUSERS.ID),0) AS FOLLOWERS,

    (SELECT IF(TOPUSERS.NAME = '',0,1) + IF(TOPUSERS.BIO = '',0,1) + IF(TOPUSERS.LOCATION = '',0,1) + IF(TOPUSERS.BIRTHDAY = '0000-00-00',0,1) + IF(TOPUSERS.GENDER = '',0,1)) as COMPLETENESS,

    CASE WHEN ? IN (SELECT USER_ID FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW_ID = TOPUSERS.ID) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS DO_I_FOLLOW_HIM

    FROM TOPUSERS
    LEFT JOIN FOLLOW ON TOPUSERS.ID = FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID
    LEFT JOIN USERS_BUCKETS ON USERS_BUCKETS.USERID=TOPUSERS.ID
    LEFT JOIN BUCKETS_NEW ON BUCKETS_NEW.ID=USERS_BUCKETS.BUCKETID

    WHERE NOT TOPUSERS.ID = ?

    GROUP BY TOPUSERS.ID ORDER BY TOPUSERS.RANDOM, TOPUSERS.USERNAME LIMIT $start, $finish");
```

When I run this in a browser it takes about 7 seconds to load. Without a few lines (the COALESCE in the middle, the two SELECTS above and the line below them) the time is reduced to 3-4 seconds.

The result of the query is a list of people with names, profile picture and some data.

Comment: This would **much** depends on the data in your database.

Comment: I'd say run it as a batch job and make it populate a table...then just read that table in the web application.

Comment: It's a VPS with MYSQL 5, PHP 5.4.30

Comment: Based on the query where should I put an INDEX?

Comment: Based on this query, indexes are irrelevant. You need a better query first, then you can think about adding indexes.

Answer (score 0):

TL,DR: you need to rewrite the query.

You need to rewrite your query to make it more efficient. I had to rewrite a similar query at work last week and here is what I have done.

The structure of your query should look like this to be efficient:

```
select ...
...
from ...
join ...
where ...
```

what you have now is something like:

```
select ...
inner select
inner select
from ...
join ...
where ...
```

That's the inner selects that kill your query. You need to find a way to move the inner select into the from section. Especially that you already query the tables.

What you need to understand is that your inner selects run for every records you have. So if you have 10 records, it would be alright (speed wise). But with hundred or thousand of records, it would be very slow.

If you want more information on your query run it with the explain keyword in from of it.